# BuildContext vs State Context

Tags: flutter

I've noticed that a state's build method passes in a BuildContext, and I've also noticed that the State itself also has a member called context.  I was wondering when it's appropriate to use the BuildContext, and when is it appropriate to use the member variable?  Are they interchangeable?

Are there times when using one over the other can cause errors and how do we take measures to insure we don't do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the flutter [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/build.html) for `State` and the build function:

> The BuildContext argument is always the same as the context property of this State object and will remain the same for the lifetime of this object. The BuildContext argument is provided redundantly here so that this method matches the signature for a WidgetBuilder.

Answer (score 5):

They are strictly equal.

It may not be obvious, but the `BuildContext` passed as parameter to `build` never ever change.

The `context` field of `State` is only pointing to that constant `BuildContext`. 
Why a duplicate ? Because `StatefulWidgets` tend to update over time. 
So you may need to access this `BuildContext` inside methods such as `didUpdateWidget`.

`StatelessWidget` doesn't need that because it only as a `build` method.